# Docker file to run Python with Pandas

Tags: docker

I have created the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python
COPY . /home
CMD pip install pandas
CMD mkdir /home/report
CMD mkdir /home/data
CMD python /home/hello.py
```

where `hello.py` is the simple Python script

```
name = input('What is your Name? ')
print('Nice to meet you', name)

from pandas import read_csv
mydf = read_csv('mycsv.csv')
print(mydf.head())
```

I then build the Docker image with `docker build -t myexample .` and run it with `docker run -it myexample bash` so as to interact with it via the shell. The building goes fine and upon running it I presented with the shell prompt, but then:

- No directories `report` or `data` have been created under `/home`.
- The last command `python /home/hello.py` does not execute on its own. I have to type it myself to get the script to run.
- Once I type `python /home/hello.py`, the first two lines that greet and prompt for my name are executed properly, but then an error says that pandas is unknown.
- It is not until I install pandas manually that the whole script runs correctly.

So, in summary, it seems that none of the `CMD` statements were taken into account. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Only  the last CMD will be valid, you should replace all  other CMD by one RUN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) an image use `RUN` to execute commands. Then, use CMD only once to declare the command that will start the container after the build (so there is only CMD):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python
RUN pip install pandas
RUN mkdir /home/report
RUN mkdir /home/data

COPY . /home
WORKDIR /home
CMD python /home/hello.py
```

mycsv.csv:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Build with: `docker build . -t pandas-test`

Run:

```
▶ docker run -it pandas-test
What is your Name? Tfovid
Nice to meet you Tfovid
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FROM python
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pandas && \
    mkdir /home/report /home/data && \
    chmod +x /home/hello.py
COPY . /home
VOLUME /home/report /home/data
WORKDIR /home
ENTRYPOINT /home/hello.py
```

Notes:

- As a general rule, it's better to collapse 2 RUN statements into one so one layer is created.
- I suggest you use a better directory than /home
- Use volumes to store data and logs.

Comment: Why do you suggest to use another directory than `/home`? Could you please give an example?